# Ext.Loader.loadScript callback called too soon

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, bing-maps

I'm trying to draw a Bing Bird's Eye View map into an ExtJS window.  I'd like to load the script just before the window is created, so I'm using Ext.Loader.loadScript like so:

```
Ext.Loader.loadScript({
    url: 'http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0',
    onLoad: function () {
        console.log(Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.birdseye);
    }
});
```

The problem is that the onLoad callback executes before the Microsoft Maps object is fully loaded, so `Microsoft.Maps.MaptypeId` is undefined.  If I open a web console a few seconds later, everything is loaded.

1. Is this a bug?
2. Is there another way to delay the callback function until the `url` and all subsequent scripts have been loaded?

Comment: for me, 'Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId' is still undefined all the times.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when the Bing Maps api loads it downloads several additional files. The initially downloaded file will trigger your onLoad function while the other resources for the Bing Maps control are being downloaded, which is why your onLoad function is firing before the Microsoft.Map namespace is fully functional. There are a couple of ways to handle this. One method is to use a timeout in your onLoad function that, when fired checks to see if the Microsoft.Maps namespace is available and the Microsoft.Maps.Map object is not undefined. If these tests fail, then have the timeout fire again after a short period of time. If they are valid, then call the function you want to run to load the map.

I also put together a blog post about lazy loading the map control here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/bing-maps-v7-control-lazy-loader/